# Scope of PDO used in a function

Tags: php, mysql, class, pdo, scope

I am using a structure like the one below -

```
class foo{
.
.
.

  function bar($colID){
     try{
        $dbo = new PDO(get_db_DSN(), 
                       get_db_USR(), 
                       get_db_PWD());
        $pstmt = $dbo->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE col=:colID");
        $pstmt->bindValue(':colID', $colID);
        $pstmt->execute();
        .
        .
        .
     }catch(PDOException e){
      ...
      }
}
```

I need to know if the PDO will persist till the object of `foo` exists or if it will be destroyed right after the end of the function's scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will be garbage collected... if you want it to be available after the function returns you should use a `foo` property to store it.

```
class foo{
.
.
.

var $dbo;  

  function bar($colID){
     try{
        $this->dbo = new PDO(get_db_DSN(), get_db_USR() get_db_PWD());

        .
        .
        .
     }catch(PDOException e){
      ...
      }
}
```

Comment: I don't want it to be available. However, is there any performances impact if I use PDO this way? I mean separate PDOs inside each functions that needs them?

Comment: there would be but it wont be noticeable. memory is freed right away.
HOWEVER depending on your DB configuration connections might be persistent or not... if they are not persistent you are going to open a new connection each time you foo->bar(). on a website that requires high availability this is a big no-no

Comment: Ah.As opposed to having a large number of persistant connections ?
Wouldn't a short sequel execution and then a disconnect be a lot less intensive on the database?

Comment: I don't think so, each query will open and close a mysql process and possibly a cpu thread. concurrency on a DB is usually not implemented at the connecting point. besides, the act of connecting is itself a process running, if you only run it once per execution you are already gaining in performance. Still, I would recommend you check this with a sysadmin. here: http://serverfault.com/ or here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

After bar `$dbo` will be "destroyed".

> Variable containers get destroyed when the "refcount" reaches zero. The "refcount" gets decreased by one when any symbol linked to the variable container leaves the scope (e.g. when the function ends) or when unset() is called on a symbol.

[Reference Counting Basics](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php)

Comment: @HanutSingh, follow the link above.